# having problem with django static file set up

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I can only and only set the static files in Django with this code

***In Installed Apps in settings.py***

```
'....',
'staticfiles',
'....
```

***In end of settings.py***

```
STATIC_URL = '/staic/'
STATICFILE_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
]
```

And It worked. At My First Time, I also tried this

***In urls.py***

```
#this way
urlpatterns = [
...,
...,
.....,

] + static(STATIC_URL, document_root=STATIC_ROOT)
#or
urlpatterns += static(STATIC_URL, document_root=STATIC_ROOT)
```

At the first time it worked but after that project this way didn't work
I viewed thousands of websites.
I did all the thing in the code like the youtube tutorial
But the second code didn't work anymore. But I cannot use the development server in production. But the first code (which works for me) requires a development server.
If Anyone knows please (if possible) give me the example code to try it, the possible answer, and all the websites where I can know more. It would be helpful.

---

### ***Thanks Very Much***

Comment: which server are you using to host the files?

Comment: I can't invest anywhere. but because at my place, the available server is Cpanel. so I cpanel information can be helpful

Comment: Show your folder structure, clarify is DEBUG=true or false.

Answer (score 1):

in `settings.py` write this code

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not a metter of URLs in your application.

As you say, django development server is not suitable for production environment.

You need a reverse proxy like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) in order to be able to serve the static files to your application and WSGI HTTP Server to run your application like [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/)

Here is a link with a very nice guide on how to setup gunicorn and nginx for django production environment.

- [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Vexxhost](https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-deploy-django-on-nginx-gunicorn-with-postgres/)
- [Medium](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dajngo-with-nginx-gunicorn-aaf8431dc9e0)

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you explain to me why my second code not working. In every other developer's code, it works. why is my one not working? Is it for the code or the wrong version that I am using?